# pandas filter on grouped item by same key

Tags: python

I have following code

```
# coding: utf-8
# Your code here!

import pandas as pd
import json
input = [
          {
              "res_id":"a",
              "lable":"la",
              "pre" : 45,
              "post": 734
          },
           {
              "res_id":"a",
              "lable":"lb",
              "pre" : 53,
              "post": 7
          },
           {
              "res_id":"a",
              "lable":"la",
              "pre" : 342,
              "post": 56
          },
           {
              "res_id":"a",
              "lable":"lb",
              "pre" : 343,
              "post": 555
          }
        ]
result = pd.DataFrame(input).groupby(['lable']).agg(lambda  x: list(x)) 

#print(result.filter(lambda x: x['lable'] == 'la'))
print(result)
print(result.post[1][1])
```

and output is

```
res_id        pre       post
lable                              
la     [a, a]  [45, 342]  [734, 56]
lb     [a, a]  [53, 343]   [7, 555]
555
>
```

now I need to filter for lable key like

to get value for la

I have tried like result['la'] or result[0], but not getting

Any help,

Thanks

Comment: Please share expected output too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.loc[]` when dealing with hierarchical indexes.

Using this you can apply filter for lable key

```
result.loc["la"]
```

```
OUTPUT:

> res_id       [a, a]
> pre       [45, 342]
> post      [734, 56]
```

Using this you can apply filter for lable key with specific column

```
result.loc["la","post"]
```

```
OUTPUT:

> [734, 56]
```

Comment: how can we get the values of lable from result.... I mean to say all the values of key used for grouping , here it should be  "la" and "lb"

Comment: If you want post values for all lable keys then try `result.loc[:,"post"]`

Comment: I want only lable value

Comment: What do you mean by lable value? provide an example.

Comment: I want to output like ['la','lb']

Comment: `list(result.index)`